# XML to powershell array

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

I want to load xml content into an array within a powershell script. Why dows this not work? :(

My XML:

```
<settings>
    <services>
       <sv>service1</sv>
       <sv>service2</sv>
    </services>
</settings>
```

My Powershell script. This seems to work, but I'm not sure

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "D:\config.xml"
[array]$service_arr = $xml.settings.services.sv
```

But now I want to display it, but I get "Cannot index into a null array."

```
$service_arr[0]
```

I don't really want to have a variable with a different generic name for each service. I only want to be able to address my services with array[0]...array[1] etc.

Comment: don't cast to array, use `$xml.settings.services.sv[0] ` and `$xml.settings.services.sv[1] `

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, because my powershell script does not know how many elements the service tag in the xml file includes.

Comment: use a foreach loop ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to cast `$xml.settings.services.sv` explicit to an `[array]`, you can just iterate over it using for example a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($service in $xml.settings.services.sv)
{
    Write-host $service
}
```